# HTML: if selected go to

Tags: html

How do i so when you pick a option in a select, then it should go to ?sort=Women ?

Comment: Don't do that. It plays havoc with anyone using the keyboard to get around the document (some people will only be able to select the first item from your select) and it gets very confusing for people who open the select to see what's in it, and then get redirected without notice when they close it again. Better to make the select part of a form and have a [GO] button next to it. That way you don't need javascript to use your page either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 onchange="window.location='?sort='+this.value"
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need Javascript for that (most probably an `onchange` event listener).

Answer (score 1):

or this

```
<select name="asd" onchange="window.location='?sort='+this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
```